# Freeing pointers left on stack after error in Bison

Tags: c, malloc, bison, flex-lexer

I'm working on a scripting language whose parser is implemented in Bison.  I don't have a question about the grammar -- it's fully functional, and the language works, but it doesn't handle errors in quite the way I want it to.

Here's the issue: I've implemented the parser so that it builds an expression tree on the stack, piece by piece, as rules are reduced. The idea is that when the entire script has been read in, I'll have a single expression tree left on the stack, which I can then convert to bytecode directly. The grammar for that particular rule looks like this:

`script:
block         { pp_write_block($1); pp_free_tree($1); 
  fputc(CODEEND,ppbcout); YYACCEPT; }
;`

Here, `pp_free_tree($1)` recursively frees the entire expression tree. This is fine -- until I encounter an error. If Bison fails at any time during the parsing, then I'm left with a bunch of heap-allocated trees on the stack.

So, my question is: how can I free these `malloc`'d trees that are sitting on the stack if I run into a parse error in Bison? Really, all I need is a way to loop through the stack, calling `pp_free_tree` on each pointer therein; I'm not sure how I would go about doing that, however.

**tl,dr**: How can I loop through the stack in Bison to free pointers I've put there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, you look for %destructor directive.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Destructor-Decl.html